# Sitecore Page Editor - "Create new content" location

Tags: sitecore, page-editor

In the page editor, when you add a new content item is it possible to automatically add it as a child of the current page?

So in page editor

- Click "Add to here" in a placeholder.
- Choose Select a rendering
- Select "create new content"
- Automatically create it as a child of the context item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by automatically you mean that Sitecore should create an item (with some name) by just selecting "Create new content", I don't believe so. You still need to provide Sitecore with a name and a location of the item that should be created.

You can however set the DataSource Location field on the sublayout/rendering to a relative path (e.g. `./Stuff`) and the "Create new content" dialog will then only allow you to create new items under that item. The `./Stuff` path will resolve to the item Stuff under the context item. I've never tried to create items as direct children of the context item so I'm not sure what the path needs to be. You could try `./` or maybe just `.`.

Comment: Although both these answers seem to achieve what I'm looking for, I'm accepting yours because it doesn't involve overriding any standard Sitecore functionality. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can overwrite how sitecore resolvs the datasource root.

Extend the pipeline "getRenderingDatasource"

And add code like this

```
public void Process(GetRenderingDatasourceArgs args){
    string datasourceLocation = args.RenderingItem["Datasource Location"];

    var item = args.ContentDatabase.GetItem(datasourceLocation)

    var templateItem = args.ContentDatabase.GetTemplate("templateName");

    Item createdItem = args.ContentDatabase.CreateItemPath(Path.Combine(item.Paths.Path, "createdItem"), templateItem);

    args.CurrentDatasource = createdItem.Paths.Path;
}
```

And then set the "Datasource Location" on the rendering or the sublayout to "."

I have not testet this specific case, but i used this method to specify datasource roots.

Comment: -1 for the untested solution (which doesn't work) and for suggesting the datasource location of the original rendering item be set to "." - this changes the datasource location of the sublayout, and this is not the desired solution, as this is required to be set dynamically for the specific rendering only.